# redundant load balancer for Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat, haproxy, high-availability

I have three Tomcat webservers in a VMWare cluster.

In the first place we thought of using Apache as a load balancer in physical server but this would be a SPOF.

I have searched around and I found this [discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/286713/is-it-possible-to-establish-more-than-one-load-balancer-with-apache?newreg=b3f95a652c3046408b03ee71310e0a25) but I would need some more info. Does it make sense to include the two (or more) HAProxy servers as virtual machines and not run them on physical servers? Can this active-passive configuration be configured using Apache? I have searched around and I found many active-passive configurations for Apache BUT as Web Server, not as a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot of experience with Apache as a reverse proxy/load balancer I don’t see any immediate reason for why it wouldn’t work.

That said, I’ve been using several virtual HAProxy pairs for almost a decade now and am very happy with that product.

From version 2.5, multithreading is very well integrated into HAProxy, so it’s trivial to scale if your traffic requires more than one core worth of capacity.

To provide a virtual IP with a primary and backup server I have installed keepalived which uses VRRP to ensure the vIP fails over to the backup proxy when it goes down.